# Relation in Py2neo with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relation, py2neo

How can i get the end node of the relation.
For example:

```
rels = graph_db.match(start_node=user, rel_type="is_post_owner")
```

So how can i get all the end nodes of the start node user.

Regards, Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
rels = graph_db.match(start_node=user, rel_type="is_post_owner")
end_nodes = [rel.end_node for rel in rels]
```

Each relationship returned from the `match` method is a standard [Relationship](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/graphs_nodes_relationships.html#py2neo.neo4j.Relationship) object and can be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cypher

```
START a=node(id) //replace with the id of the node you want to start 
MATCH p=a-[:is_post_owner*..]->x //get all the paths to all nodes with rel:is_post_owner
WHERE NOT(x-->()) //exclude nodes with Direction Out Relationships "end nodes"
RETURN x //get the end nodes
```

That way returned nodes are going to be leaf nodes of your graph, with no other relationship with direction out.

As Thomas stated, in which he is absolutely right, you should include the relationship type in the where clause.That way you are getting the end node of that relationship only and returned nodes can have other relationships with direction out (not leaf nodes) but they are the end nodes of the requested relationship

```
 START a=node(id) 
 MATCH p=a-[r:is_post_owner*..]->x 
 WHERE NOT(x-->(r)) 
 RETURN x
```

Comment: You should add the relation type into the WHERE not, there might be other, unrelated ones